# Difference between background-attachment:fixed and position : fixed

Tags: css

im a beginner in CSS , and i am confused with this 2 ... Who can explain me what is the difference between  background-attachment:fixed and position : fixed ???

Comment: So what is it ???

Comment: posted an answer ,hope you got it?

Comment: why not search `background-attachment:fixed` and `position:fixed` on the WEB and see what you can find ?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url('w3css.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
p{
position: fixed;
color:Red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>

<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>If you do not see any scrollbars, try to resize the browser window.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Background-attachment:fixed is for positioning an **Image** where as , position :fixed; is for elements like p ,span ,div.

Comment: You're welcome :)Hey sorry,I misunderstood the question first.That's why  I commented that It was not a question :(

Comment: Dont worry bro :)